# Adding a click event to a dynamically generated button in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So i'm currently trying to get a simply cart working in a website. Basically, as the items are displayed from your cart on the cart page, a panel is populated with images, labels and buttons relating to each one.

What I want to do is assign a click event to every button created that calls a generic method to remove that item from the list. Here's the code for removing the item from the arraylist of items:

```
public void Remove(CartItem item)
{ 
    ArrayList remove = (ArrayList)Session["ShoppingBasket"];
    remove.Remove(item);
}
```

This is the event handler I'm trying to code for every button that's generated:

```
btnRemove.Click += new EventHandler(Remove(item));
```

For some reason, an error message is coming up saying that a method name is expected in the above line of code and I can't see where I'm going wrong. I'm not too familiar with using the EventHandler object so any guidance there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EventHandler should match the signature of the Event. You can't just pass any method as an EventHandler. You need a proper void matching the signature of the event.

You can instead try a lambda expression:

```
btnRemove.Click += (_sender, _args) => Remove(item);
```

You could have used a separate method but since you need to pass the `item` to the function `Remove`, you need to use to use a lambda expression to be able to access `item` in the context.

Comment: `new EventHandler` is redundant. Simplify it like this: `btnRemove.Click += (s, e) => Remove(item);`

Comment: @user2946329 Yes. I just copied it from the Original Post.

Comment: I've tried this method but now its having a problem with the EventArgs parameter. it says: "e cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter". Should I just use a different name for 'e'?

Comment: Oh, yes if you use this in another handler then you can just use a different name, it will work fine.

Comment: @Mark Consider accepting this answer so that future readers can find it useful too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

btnRemove.Click += (e,s)=> remove(item)

Comment: o yes, i just run IDE to check it syntactically while other posted answer.